# How to underscore the email and password edittext fields?

Tags: android, android-edittext

G'day guys, 
Most likely a simple fix however I'm new to all this...

I'm making a basic login page, for an app, however, the email and password 'EditText' fields aren't displaying the underscore to define the fields... Any way to turn them on?

Picture for reference:https://i.gyazo.com/e5747592689b1e8ddc15e0667caa5dae.png

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_login"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
tools:context="com.example.living_instinkt.maintlog.LoginActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:id="@+id/etEmail"
    android:hint="Email"
    android:textColorHint="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:id="@+id/etPass"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:textColorHint="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Create a *drawable* resource `text_underscore_line.xml` and have an item with the bottom border to white color like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="-2dp"
        android:right="-2dp"
        android:top="-2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <stroke
                android:width="0.5dp"
                android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Then use the *drawable* as a *background* for your `EditText` like this:

```
<EditText
    android:background="@drawable/text_underscore_line"
    ... />
```

**RESULT**

[image]

Comment: Thanks mate! I feel there should be an easier way.... Or maybe just have the underscores as default but got it sorted so thanks! :P

Comment: @LivingInstinkt you're welocme. I don't think there is another way to do this. This is not *HTML* with *CSS*, Android UI is based on *XML*. And you can't use the underscore char in any case. If you find my answer useful, then please mark it as accepted answer. To see how you can accept an answer, please read here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work